# Why am I getting a FileNotFound exception when referencing another project from the same solution?

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

I am learning how to use NUnit.  I have my main project in it's solution, and created a separate project in that same solution which will hold my unit tests, with it's own namespace.  From that project I add a reference to the main project and add a

```
using MainProjectNamespace;
```

to the top of it.

When I go to NUnit, any tests I have that don't reference the main project work.  These are tests I setup just to get used to NUnit, and are pretty much useless.  When NUnit runs the real tests the test throws this exception:

> TestLibrary.Test.TestMainProject: 
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException :
>   Could not load file or assembly
>   'WpfApplication2, Version = 1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>   or one of its dependencies.  The
>   system cannot find the specified file.

Why am I getting this exception?

EDIT:

Now when I try to load the assembly into NUnit, it won't even load (so I can't even get a chance to run the tests)

This is the Exception that come sup, and the stack trace:

System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'LONG PATH HERE I DON'T WANT TO TYPE'

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException...

Server stack trace: 
    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
    at System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(String path)
    at NUnit.Core.DirectorySwapper..ctor(String directoryName)
    at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Load(String path)
    at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName, Boolean autoSuites)
    at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName, String testName, Boolean autoSuites)
    at NUnit.Core.TestSuiteBuilder.Build(TestPackage package)
    at NUnit.Core.SimpleTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
    at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
    at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
    at NUnit.Core.RemoteTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.PrivateProcessMessage(RuntimeMethodHandle md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
    at NUnit.Core.TestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
    at NUnit.Util.TestDomain.Load(TestPackage package)
    at NUnit.Util.TestLoader.LoadTest(String testName)
```

EDIT2:
The above path clearly IS in my hard drive

EDIT3:
I just switched from Debug to Release, on NUnit, and loaded the dll from the release folder of TestingLibrary...  And it loaded!  1 of the 3 namespace-specific tests worked.  Getting somewhere, I am.

EDIT4:
Welllllllll...  I can actually run the tests now, but I am back to the original error.  IT is not finding the assembly for the main project

Comment: Are you running into problems with relative vs absolute paths?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler removes all unused references, and doesn't deploy the dll unnecessarily. A `using` (by itself) does not count as a use. Either mark the dll for deployment via the "Copy to output directory" setting, or add some code that *really* uses types declared in the dll.

Comment: I have some code in there that creates a new instance of a class and does a few things.  But the error still comes up.

Comment: Also, the "Copy Local" property is set, which indicates whether the reference will be copied to the output directory.

Comment: Marc, check your new comments.  I can't get this thing to work, and you always have all the answers...

Comment: Not all the time, I don't - sorry. The only other thought I have at the moment is "something to do with the SNK"... is anything strong-named?

Comment: in the Test class most of the references are Strong Named, the only one that isn't is the reference to the main project

Answer (score 1):

Did you rename the name of the output assembly OR namespace in the source project?

Looks like your source file is "WPFApplication1" & I am speculating that you might have changed the output type from dll to exe?

Comment: I did rename a few things when I was creating the original project, perhaps this messed something up?  The new project's intellisense can figure out the types of my custom class objects, but for some reason itis causing trouble...

Comment: I renamed the namespace for sure.

Comment: OK. Delete the reference to the assembly from "References" (it might show the reference with an exclamation mark). Build your source project & add the reference of it to the Test project.

Comment: you mean delete the reference to the original project from the testing project?

Comment: I did the above, and rebuilt the original project, then added a reference to the testing project, and rebuilt it as well, still getting the same error

Comment: Create a new test project. I think that will save you some time.

Comment: none of the details of the original project have changed since creating the Testing project

Comment: I just made a new project, and now when I got o load the dll in NUnit it won't even let me load it.  It gives me the same error as I was getting when running the tests except I am getting it when NUnit tries to load the assembly.

Comment: wait, the above statement is false, actually I am getting s SIMILAR meesage but this time it can't find the NUnit framework dll

Comment: I will suggest close vs.net. Open the solution having source project. Add new project, add reference to nunit.framework.dll & your project. Add the source file for test & build the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and RKitsons answer helped me.

Basically I copied all the dll's that my project depends on as well as the nunit.framework.dll into the same directory...obj/debug/ THis is one way of doing it.

The elegant method is to change the project configuration , in Visual Studio, under the Build tab to release mode and if the project is setup correctly should copy all the dependent dll's into an appropriate  "out" or "release" directory.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of the assemblies you are referencing in your app has dependencies on another assembly which is not in your bin folder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I just checked my bin folder and both the debug and release subfolders contain all of the files that my TestLibrary depends on.  Such as WpfApplication2.exe...  Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to use the NUnit console App?  If so, have you tried TestDriven.net?  I was getting a similar error a few weeks ago, but it was because I was using a few different open source projects that all depended upon another project, but different versions.

Comment: Does TestDriven.NET work with VS Express?  I am not seeing the "Run Tests"