# Getting Error while loading the project in the NUnit

Tags: selenium, c#-4.0, nunit

I'm trying the load the project in the NUnit GUI. But I'm getting an error

```
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
at System.IO.File.Open(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
at WellsFargo.Tridion.NUnit.DailyMonitoringTesting.TestDataFactory.GetInputData(String NodeName) in C:\Users\u382343\Desktop\PQC Patching Project\source\WellsFargo.Tridion.NUnit.DailyMonitoringTesting\Common\TestDataFactory.cs:line 153
at WellsFargo.Tridion.NUnit.DailyMonitoringTesting.TestDataFactory.<get_F5Url>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Users\u382343\Desktop\PQC Patching Project\source\WellsFargo.Tridion.NUnit.DailyMonitoringTesting\Common\TestDataFactory.cs:line 21
at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestCaseSourceProvider.GetTestCasesFor(MethodInfo method, Test parentSuite)
at NUnit.Core.Extensibility.TestCaseProviders.GetTestCasesFor(MethodInfo method, Test suite)
```

Can anyone tell me what's this error about?

Answer (score 0):

If all the required/dependent dlls are not properly copied to release folder you are trying to load the NUnit GUI, this error will be thrown.

Please refer: [Why am I getting a FileNotFound exception when referencing another project from the same solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525064/why-am-i-getting-a-filenotfound-exception-when-referencing-another-project-from)